# ibus not appearing in StatusNotifierItem spec-compliant system tray

Tags: ibus, tray

This one is tricky as I have heavily customized my setup, but it has been bothering me a lot so I decided to ask a question.

Recently, `ibus` stopped appearing on the system tray. While my system tray is not the typical one people use, it does comply to the freedesktop's StatusNotifierItem specification. I don't think a program as famous as `ibus` would have status notifier not compliant to the standard.

Do you have any clue what is happening? Which system diagnostics could I dig up to pinpoint the problem? Any direction (excluding "use another system tray") would be appreciated!

EDIT: The option "Show icon on system tray" is definitely turned on.

Comment: hadn't this (ibus icon appearing in the status notifier) been made optional some time ago ? https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/513

Comment: Forgot to mention this - I checked the "show ibus icon" option on. Even tried turning it off and on. Doesn't work.